# Парсится не тот элемент

Tags: python, selenium, bs4

Я пытаюсь спарсить сайт https://www.rlsnet.ru/drugs/ukazatel/c0, в данном случае - побочные действия лекарств. Они хранятся в теге p с классом OPIS_POLE. Таких элементов на странице много, но выводится у меня почему-то только адрес, который вообще в конце. Пыталась брать элемент по индексу, но в любом случае выводится только адрес.

Как это можно исправить?

В комментариях способ с селениумом, который я тоже пробовала (работает медленней, но результат тот же).

```
options = Options()
executable_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'chromedriver', 'chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, 
service=Service(executable_path=executable_path))

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

driver.get("https://www.rlsnet.ru/drugs/ukazatel/c0")
time.sleep(3)
links = []

links_scope = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.link')

for one_link in links_scope:
    links.append(one_link.get_attribute('href'))

for link in links[2:]:
    try:
        driver.get(link)
        time.sleep(3)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        #opis_pole = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.break-word > p.OPIS_POLE'))).text
        opis_pole = soup.find_all('p', class_='OPIS_POLE')
        print(opis_pole)
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup вам зачем? сначало driver.get() потом driver.page_source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, проблема в том что страница динамическая, вы брали page_source сразу же после того как открываете страницу.
Действительно, к чему вы пришли, взять код страницы спустя некоторое время является верным (Это можно сделать либо использовав time.sleep(), либо явное ожидание погрузки WebDriverWait(), а уже затем брать page_source)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена тем, что объект soup нужно поместить внутрь try, после загрузки ссылки :)